# Adding a Theme Customizer Control for Posts_Per_Page

Tags: wp-query, pre-get-posts, theme-customizer

I am trying to add a Theme Customizer Control to change the number of posts shown in my WP_Query posts_per_page, like so...

```
$posts_per_page_option = get_option( 'posts_per_page_option' ); 
$query_blog = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page='.$posts_per_page_option.'',));
   if ( $query_blog->have_posts() ) : while ( $query_blog->have_posts() ) : $query_blog->the_post();
```

Not having much luck, any ideas?

Comment: there's already an option for this. if you're going to expose it in the customizer (not a bad idea) you should use the existing option value for consistency. what exactly is the issue you're encountering?

Comment: Thanks, I have a separate 'featured posts' area of my theme to which i would like the user to be able to select the number of posts to display in the Customizer.

This would not control the existing option for 'Blog pages show at most' in Theme Settings.

Answer (score 0):

You are so very close. In your first line just replace `get_option` with [`get_theme_mod`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mod) and you're done, provided you have already [added a customizer control](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_control) for `posts_per_page_option` in the usual way.